# Get last_login time for a certain user? (django)

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have the code `User.objects.values_list('last_login',flat= True)` Which gives me a list of all of the last logins for all of the users but I'm unsure how you slim that done to a specific user. I tried code along the lines of `User.objects.get(username='user1').values_list('last_login',flat= True)` But that didn't work. I think I need something between the first set of paren's and values_list but I not sure what I would put there in order for them to link up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='user1')
last_login = user.last_login
```

Answer (score 4):

As you look at Django docs `values_list` is under [Methods that return new QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets). So it is not applicable on single object as you did. And [last_login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.last_login) is field of `User` model so you can access it directly by,

```
User.objects.get(username='user1').last_login
```