# How to display the last login date and time on the users list on the django admin site?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've built a social authentication system on an django application using the social_django app. It works and I can see users on the admin site as well. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

What I want is to see the last login date and time in the list too. How can I accomplish that? I am using sqlite3 as a database and 2.1.4 of django.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352495/get-last-login-time-for-a-certain-user-django

Comment: You have to unregister the `User` model from the admin and then register it again with your own custom `UserAdmin` class that includes 'last_login' in the `list_display`

Answer (score 7):

`Admin.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'last_login') # Added last_login

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Inherit from the main `UserAdmin`, do you customization, then unregister `User` then register it again with the Admin you created

Comment: Not working for me, should I add to `admin.py` of any specific app?

Comment: @kiran add it in any `admin.py` in an app registered in `INSTALLED_APPS`